# Python random color nested for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

For this python code I'm making squares that are being drawn in random locations on the screen, I need each square to be a random color too. Everything is working except the random color. The turtle is the only thing that changes colors. I'm not sure where to the color codes, either outside or in the nested for loop.

```
import random
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle

window = turtle.Screen()
bob = turtle.Turtle()

window.setup(1000,1000)

window.colormode(255)
red = random.randint(0,255)
green = random.randint(0,255)
blue = random.randint(0,255)



for i in range(10):
    box_size = random.randint(50,100)
    x = random.randint(-250,250)
    y = random.randint(-250,250)
    bob.fillcolor(red, green, blue)
    for j in range(4):
        bob.begin_fill()
        bob.forward(box_size)
        bob.left(90)
        bob.end_fill()
    bob.penup()
    bob.goto(x,y)
    bob.pendown()
```

[image]

This is what the code looks like running, I was able have the code draw the squares just how I want it, but each square needs a random color to be using the begin_fill() function.

Comment: maybe you can set a list of colours and let it goes through the list, each time picking one or random

Comment: The random values that are actually working are generated inside the loop.  The random colors that aren't working are generated *before* the loop.  Do you see a pattern here?

Answer (score 0):

The squares are not colored as expected since you're not using the `begin_fill` and `end_fill` properly.

In the following block of your code, you call `begin_fill`/`end_fill` every time you draw a line, that's why it's not working.

```
for j in range(4):
    bob.begin_fill()
    bob.forward(box_size)
    bob.left(90)
    bob.end_fill()
```

The correct way in doing that:

```
bob.begin_fill()
  for j in range(4):
      bob.forward(box_size)
      bob.left(90)
bob.end_fill()
```

Also, as @jasonharper pointed out in the comment, the colors of the squares won't look as you expected since you are not updating the `red`, `green`, and `blue` values in the for loop that creates the squares.

References:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.begin_fill
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.end_fill